Can gym equipment be Medically Necessary under the terms of the FSA?
Currently, I go to the gym only to do squats? I have a back problem that caused a lasting injury and basically left me disabled for six months.
By working out my core, I prevent the injury from recurring.
I know ergonomic chairs can be medically necessary. I also know gym membership can be medically necessary. Can gym equipment, in my case a squat rack, be medically necessary too?

Gym - probably not. Physical therapy - yes, it should be covered by your medical insurance and is FSA eligible.

@littleadv that sounds like a "be sure you call the purchase the right thing" note. My Physical Therapy doctor had a squat rack inside. It's the same model (or close to it) that my gym uses. But sure, better to talk the talk.

You could argue that food is "medically necessary". That doesn't mean that it's an eligible expense under FSA rules.  The IRS determines what's an eligible expense, not common sense.

@EvanCarroll I had a medical necessity letter for a pressure ball from my PT provider challenged - a $10 expense. Anything that can be used for things other than your healthcare will likely be challenged, and the denial chances grow exponentially as a function of the possibility of unrelated use.

@DStanley That's correct. Please cite what the rules permit. Do they permit a "squat rack" if it's for prescribed at home "physical therapy"

@EvanCarroll See the IRS Pub 502.

@EvanCarroll From the link above - "you can't include membership dues in a gym, health club, or spa."

My point was that just because something is "medically necessary" does not mean it is an eligible FSA expense - the publication lists what is and is not eligible.

In my experience, most of the IRS rules are common sense when you look at the more carefully. Sometimes inconvenient common sense, admittedly. And sometimes an arbitrary line must be drawn because otherwise no line can be drawn. But I have seen very little from the IRS that I actively disagree with, and most of that makes sense given the society's biases.
